# Is There Stable Video Conversation (Through Webcams) Support Available on Linux?

Tags: linux, webcam, instant-messaging

Is there stable video conversation support (via webcam) on Linux? If so, using what protocols and what applications?

Is it possible to a Windows user from Linux, if so what programs or protocols support this?

I know that Ekiga support is coming along, does anyone know how good the current implementation is or has had any experience with it?

P.S. If anyone asks, by 'stable' I mean good quality and infrequent dropouts.

**Edit: This question has been edited to be clearer that I mean video conversation support and not just webcam support.**

Skype has been suggested by [Nifle](https://superuser.com/users/2013/nifle), are there any other good solutions?

Answer (score 5):

I use [skype](http://www.skype.com) on both windows and linux and have no problems (lately).

Comment: Although the linux version of skype is light years behind in support, is usable enough.

Comment: Skype is actually pretty good. There's a new beta version 2.1.0.47 released recently, as well. It doesn't have many features for the camera itself, but it works well.

Answer (score 2):

my wife's netbook (Asus eee 900) has a built in webcam and runs linux. Skype runs fine on it, apart from that i can't really help you out.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.linux-drivers.org/usb_webcams.html) lists a bunch of drivers and supported USB webcams.  It should be the first website that you check.  Not much in the way of testimonials or ratings, so you may want to pick a webcam you're interested in and Google it.

Answer (score 0):

[aMSN](http://www.amsn-project.net/) has full webcam support.